# Slice not working in jQuery multiplication

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 2 values in my HTML, 1 is an input value whereas the other is HTML. I simply want to divide 1 value by the other (which is working well), but it produces a huge sum.

So all I want to do is take the first 4 charactersof this sum. So e.g. If the value is 1.43574322, this will take 1.43.

```
<div id="upload-final" class="final-stats">201.1</div>
<input type="text" id="yourprice" maxlength="10" placeholder="Price" value="100">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" ></script>

<script>
    var strw = $("#yourprice").val() / $("#upload-final").html();
    $('#yourspendmbps').html(strw).slice(0, 4);
</script>
```

Could someone please advise where I am going wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: Most jQuery methods return the jQuery object itself again - that is necessary for "method chaining", so that you can call `$(...).foo().bar()` in direct succession. But the jQuery object does not have a `slice` method ... You need to apply slice to `strw` here.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe I tried this but hitting the following error:- Uncaught TypeError: strw.slice is not a function

Comment: Right, because you do not have a string value here, but a number. `(''+ strw).slice(...)` should work, concatenation with the empty string forces the whole thing to become a string value.

Comment: Although, simply cutting off numeric values after a certain amount of digits, probably doesn't make the most sense for many cases. Maybe you should rather go look into how to _round_ a number to a certain amount of decimals.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are slicing not a number but jquery object.

**$('#yourspendmbps').html(strw)**.slice(0, 4);

You should use

```js
$('#yourspendmbps').html(strw.slice(0, 4));
```

**BUT**
You are trying to slice a floating point number.
You can only slice array or strings which are arrays.
So to make it work simple convert your `strw` to string

```html
<div id="upload-final" class="final-stats">201.1</div>
<input type="text" id="yourprice" maxlength="10" placeholder="Price" value="100">
<div id="yourspendmbps"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" ></script>

<script>
    var strw = ($("#yourprice").val() / $("#upload-final").html()) +'';
    $('#yourspendmbps').html(strw.slice(0, 4));
</script>
```